# spring security filter issues

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

using Boot 2.1.14.Release / security 5.1.10

I have the following endpoints which need the specified security

`/token/exchange` - this endpoint should only allow access if the request has an Okta JWT.  It returns a custom JWT I've create manually via JJWT.  Basically, instead of passing in user creds, the users will have already authenticated with Okta and will provide that token as their credential.

I've added the Okta starter and this is working as expected

---

`/api/**` - any endpoint under `/api` requires my custom JWT in the Authorization header

---

I have the following security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class AppWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class OktaWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/token/exchange") <------- this should "pin" this config right?
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/token/exchange").authenticated() <--- is this needed?
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
            http.cors();
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final CustomSecurityConfig customSecurityConfig; <--- JWT secret key in here
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .addFilter(new JwtFilter(authenticationManager(), customSecurityConfig))
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .cors();
        }
    }
}
```

and the following `JwtFilter`

```
@Slf4j
public class JwtFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    private final CustomSecurityConfig customSecurityConfig;

    public JwtFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, CustomSecurityConfig customSecurityConfig) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.customSecurityConfig = customSecurityConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);
            if (authentication == null) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception exception){
            log.error("API authentication failed", exception);
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = new DefaultBearerTokenResolver().resolve(request);
        if (token == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(customSecurityConfig.getSecret());
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
                .withIssuer(CustomSecurityConfig.ISSUER)
                .build();
        DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                jwt.getClaim("user_name").asString(),
                null,
                jwt.getClaim("authorities")
                        .asList(String.class)
                        .stream()
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

My `/api` calls all return 401 and its because they are being processed by the `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` (used by my `OktaWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`) instead of my `JwtFilter`.  Naturally, the signatures don't match between the two tokens.  I'm confused why my `/api` calls are even being processed by that filter, because I'm only applying the `.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();` config for my Okta handler

my logs look like this:

```
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Checking match of request : '/api/entities'; against '/token/exchange'
Checking match of request : '/api/entities'; against '/api/**'
/api/entities at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/api/entities at position 2 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
/api/entities at position 3 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
/api/entities at position 4 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
/api/entities at position 5 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
Checking match of request : '/api/entities'; against '/logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
Request 'GET /api/entities' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
Request 'GET /api/entities' doesn't match 'PUT /logout'
Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
Request 'GET /api/entities' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout'
No matches found
/api/entities at position 6 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter'
Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider
No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException
Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Another algorithm expected, or no matching key(s) found
Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@13691de5
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

I've been banging my head all day and night with this....thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with the answer to your question (I think).  You are adding your filter with `addFilter(...)` which doesn't specify any order information. Use `addFilterBefore(...)` instead.

I would caution you against using JWT for a sort of session token unless have a way to revoke them. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens

In your case, it sounds like you might be exchanging one token for a "weaker" one. There are things you can do to mitigate some of this risk, like limiting the duration the token is valid, etc.  I don't have all of the context of your use case or how you are using it, so take this with a grain of salt :)

Comment: > In your case, it sounds like you might be exchanging one token for a "weaker" one
exactly...I inherited some really bad code and I'm trying not to alter the domain logic which requires a signed token (I won't even call it a JWT).  My goal is to protect a single route with OAuth2, which will return a custom build and signed token.  Any endpoint behind /api/** needs to require that signed token.  @brian-demers

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in the [JJWT](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#verification-key) readme

> But you might have noticed something - what if your application doesn't use just a single SecretKey or KeyPair? What if JWSs can be created with different SecretKeys or public/private keys, **or a combination of both?** How do you know which key to specify if you can't inspect the JWT first?

that led me to rethink the design.

basically, all my routes expect a Bearer token.  One of them (`/token/exchange`) expects the token came from Okta.  All of my `/api/**` routes expect the token to be a signed by the API server itself.  To accomplish this, I setup a singular security config like so:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyCustomSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
                .cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

My `JwtFilter`

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String HEADER = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;

    private final OktaTokenUtils oktaTokenUtils;
    private final ApiTokenUtils apiTokenUtils;

    public JwtFilter(OktaTokenUtils oktaTokenUtils, ApiTokenUtils apiTokenUtils) {
        this.oktaTokenUtils = oktaTokenUtils;
        this.apiTokenUtils = apiTokenUtils;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String header = request.getHeader(HEADER);
        if (header != null && !header.isBlank()) {
            final String token = header.substring(7);
            log.debug("{} TOKEN: {}", HEADER, token);
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            if (uri.equals("/token/exchange")) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(oktaTokenUtils.authenticate(token));
            } else {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(apiTokenUtils.authenticate(token));
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

My OktaUtils and ApiUtils classes are responsible for validating the token and returning the Authentication object so the filter can add it to the security context holder

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ApiTokenUtils {

    private final JwtParser parser;

    public ApiTokenUtils(ApiTokenConfig config){
        parser = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .requireIssuer(config.getIssuer())
                .setSigningKey(config.getSecret())
                .build();
    }

    public Authentication authenticate(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = parser.parseClaimsJws(token);
            String username = claims.getBody().get("user_name", String.class);
            log.debug("valid API token for username {}", username);
            List<String> authorities = claims.getBody().get("authorities", List.class);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    username,
                    null,
                    authorities.stream()
                            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
            authentication.setDetails(MyUserDetails.builder()
                    .token(token)
                    .authorities(authorities)
                    .setUserId(claims.getBody().get("userId", String.class))
                    .email(claims.getBody().get("email", String.class))
                    .username(username)
                    .build());
            return authentication;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {
                log.error("API token verification failed", e);
            } else {
                log.error("API token verification failed");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class OktaTokenUtils {

    private final AccessTokenVerifier verifier;

    public OktaTokenUtils(OktaConfig oktaConfig) {
        verifier = JwtVerifiers.accessTokenVerifierBuilder()
                .setIssuer(oktaConfig.getIssuer())
                .setAudience(oktaConfig.getAudience()) // defaults to 'api://default'
                .setConnectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)) // defaults to 1s
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3)) // defaults to 1s
                .build();
    }

    public Authentication authenticate(String token) {
        try {
            Jwt jwt = verifier.decode(token);
            String subject = jwt.getClaims().get("sub").toString();
            log.debug("valid Okta token for SUB {}", subject);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    subject,
                    token,
                    Collections.emptyList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) {
                log.error("Okta token verification failed", e);
            } else {
                log.error("Okta token verification failed");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

some links that helped me along the way:

- https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-java
- https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt